# Burninate [java.lang.linkageerror] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[java.lang.linkageerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java.lang.linkageerror) seems so out of place as a tag; it has 56 questions currently, most of them also tagged with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), which should do better as a replacement for those without it already.

I hope we don't end up with fully qualified Java class names as tags everywhere...

Comment: Hard to turn this one into a pun...

Comment: @isUserAGoat Unlink [java.lang.linkageerror]?

Comment: [java.lang.linkageerror] is getting old...

Comment: Here are more fully qualified Java class name tags to check if they really should exist: [tag:java.lang]: 7 [tag:java.lang.class]: 59. Even more if you search the tags for `java.util`

Comment: @Ferrybig I'd say that the `java.util.*` tags are actually good (at least for the most part) since, for instance, Java's `Scanner` class has many problems associated specifically with it.

Comment: @Ferrybig Regarding the [tag:java.lang] tag, I went through them and removed it from most of the questions, since they had nothing to do with `java.lang`. Most of them were about some exception whose fully qualified name starts with `java.lang`

Comment: @BalusC - while I may be capable, I haven't done much of anything with tags before, nor am familiar with the general consensus you're referring to. Good to know my intuition was on though.

Comment: And it is done.